# Changing paths in Delphi

Tags: delphi, search, video

I am working on a project where I need to play a video from a file in Delphi. I often work from home and school, and I have the problem that at home, my USB is drive 'J' and at school my USB is drive 'D'.

I manually go and change it every time. Is there a way for Delphi to automatically get the video from where ever it is?

Each sector has an image component laid over it for selecting the sector.

*Note, I know I can search for a specific file's location in Delphi, but I have over 24 different places where I need to play different videos, so searching would probably be my last resort, unless I use a procedure and set constants for each sector to differenciate between them.

The code currently looks as follows:

```
procedure TtForm.imgSector1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  
    //Variables,this is for initializing them when I create them later.                                                                                                                                             

  //Procedures                                                                                                   
      SectorDeselect; //Procedure to turn all sector borders white                                            

  // Video                                                                                                       
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.stop;                                                                        
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := 'J:\IT\PAT\phase 2\Videos\Footage1.mp4'; //Where my problem lies             
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.Play;

  // Sector Info. The memos and Rich edits                                                                                                                                                                       
  redSectorInfo.Lines.Clear;                                                                                                                                                                              
  redSectorInfo.Lines.Add('');                                                                                                                                                             

  // Sector. Highlighting the sector borders surrounding the sector                                                                                                   
  SectorBordr1.Brush.Color := clGreen;                                                                          
  SectorBorder10.Brush.Color := clGreen;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
end;
```

Comment: But don't do that in a real app, of course.

Comment: Store the files next to your exe or in a subfolder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest adding a TEdit control in your app's UI to let you specify the base drive/path for the files on the machine the app is currently running on. Your code can then construct individual file paths at runtime that are relative to that base path. Don't use hard-code paths in your code.

You can then save that base path into the Windows Registry in a new key you create, ie `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp`. Or, you can save the path in a configuration file (INI, XML, JSON, etc) created in a subfolder in your Windows user profile, like `%APPDATA%\MyApp`. Your code can then read in that base path each time the app is run.

If the files are stored on a USB drive, an alternative solution would be to simply enumerate the available drives at runtime, such as with [`GetLogicalDriveStrings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrivestringsw). For each drive, append a relative path for a given file onto the end of it, and then check if that file exists, such as with [`FileExists()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FileExists). If so, you now know which drive to use for all of the files until the next time your app is run (you can save the drive path between runs, as described above). If the file is not found, move on to the next drive.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a parameter on the CommandLine?

Start

D:\myfolder\myfile D

OR

Start

J:\myfolder\myfile J

GUI files can accept a parameter.  Capture it with code like:

DriveLetter := ParamStr(1);

Comment: Thanks, but this would be hardcoding it.